# sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed:

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-security

we are facing a weird issue when running our server using sqlalchemy and flask_security

sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: user.fs_uniquifier
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (email, username, password, active, super_saas_admin, fs_uniquifier, confirmed_at, tf_phone_number, tf_primary_method, tf_totp_secret) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('test@me.com', None, 'password', 1, None, None, None, None, None, None)]

Would anyone have an idea on what could cause this?

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template_string
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, auth_required, RoleMixin, UserMixin
from flask_security.models import fsqla_v2 as fsqla

# Create app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

# Generate a nice key using secrets.token_urlsafe()
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY", 'xxxxx')
# Bcrypt is set as default SECURITY_PASSWORD_HASH, which requires a salt
# Generate a good salt using: secrets.SystemRandom().getrandbits(128)
app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'] = os.environ.get("SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT", 'xxxxxx')

# Use an in-memory db
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
# As of Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.4.0 it is easy to pass in options directly to the
# underlying engine. This option makes sure that DB connections from the
# pool are still valid. Important for entire application since
# many DBaaS options automatically close idle connections.
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS"] = {
    "pool_pre_ping": True,
}
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

# Create database connection object
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Define models
fsqla.FsModels.set_db_info(db)

# Define models
roles_users = db.Table('roles_users_2',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id')))

class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
  description = db.Column(db.String(255))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    # Make username unique but not required.
    username = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    super_saas_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users, backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
    fs_uniquifier = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    tf_phone_number = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=True)
    tf_primary_method = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=True)
    tf_totp_secret = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)


# Setup Flask-Security
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)

# Create a user to test with
@app.before_first_request
def create_user():
    db.create_all()
    if not user_datastore.find_user(email="test@me.com"):
        user_datastore.create_user(email="test@me.com", password="password")
    db.session.commit()

# Views
@app.route("/")
@auth_required()
def home():
    return render_template_string("Hello {{ current_user.email }}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I *think* might be going on - you are using the fsqla models that are shipped with Flask-Security - however you are ALSO completely defining your OWN user model - my guess is that there are 2 User models running around and the system is getting confused. What you should try is:

```
class User(db.Model, fsqla.FsUserMixin):
    super_sass_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean) # add your additional fields
```

And thats it.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I have tried to make the changes but the problem still persists. This error is still thrown even when copying the public code example of "flask security too" available here https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#sqlalchemy-application

Would you have any idea on what could be going on please? Thanks!

Comment: I just cut and paste the quickstart example and it works fine for me using python 3.9. I am guessing there must be something in your code or environment that would cause this - you might try creating a brand new venv and trying out the quickstart example to get a baseline.

Answer (score -1):

This is occurring for me with PyCharm. I am supposing you have a module that contains your app, and a file that runs it external to the module.

2 options both worked for me:

1. Move the file that runs the app into the module. I moved it into `app.py` in the module, but I understand that in some environments this can cause problems.
2. Run the file from the terminal tab with `python <file>.py`. This requires you to be inside the virtual environment for app if you have created one.